# Storing large objects in Firebase and access only parts of them

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wonder what would be the most load-time-efficient way to store data in Firebase for the following scenario:

There are several text documents, each consisting of a number of paragraphs like so:

```
doc1 {
  title: 'first doc',
  author: 'John Doe',
  creation_date: 1234567890,
  paragraphs: {
    p001{
      text:'This is the first paragraph',
      …}
    p002{
      text:'This is the second paragraph',
      …}
  }
}
```

If I want to display one of those documents, I simply get a data snapshot and get the entire object `doc1` from the network.

This approach seems a bit odd once I want to display only the `title` but of all documents. Is there a way to exclude some children from being loaded? Or is it necessary to restructure the database and collect a `overview`object, that only contains the keys and titles of all documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When retrieving data from the Firebase database it always returns complete nodes. So while you could get just the title of a document (with `/documents/doc1/title`) you cannot get just the titles of a list of documents.

The Firebase documentation recommends that you don't nest different types of data under a common root. One of the reasons for this, is precisely what you're now asking: you'll often want to retrieve the metadata of a book without retrieving the rest of the contents.

So an alternative (and more common) way to model the data would be:

```
documents: {
    doc1: {
      title: 'first doc',
      author: 'John Doe',
      creation_date: 1234567890,
    },
    doc2: {
      title: 'second doc',
      author: 'nehalem',
      creation_date: 1234567891,
    }
},
paragraphs: {
    doc1: {
      p001{
        text:'This is the first paragraph',
        …}
      p002{
        text:'This is the second paragraph',
        …}
    },
    doc2: {
      p001{
        text:'This is the first paragraph',
        …}
      p002{
        text:'This is the second paragraph',
        …}
    }
}
```

Now you can get the title, authors and creation date for showing a list by reading/querying `/documents` and then get the paragraph for a specific book by reading `/paragraphs/doc1`.